# Remove one field from mongoDB collection

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have a mongoDB collection which I use with a mongoose Schema :

```
const balanceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user'
    },
    incomes: { Number },
    fees: { Number },
},
    { strict: false })
```

I use the strict mode to false, so I can push any 'key' I want with its value.

I would like to delete just one of the "incomes" category, but I can't specify the line because there is no 'defined key'.
Here is an exemple of the data inside :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60c763df3d260204865d2069"
    },
    "incomes": {
        "income1": 1300,
        "anyKeyNameIWant": 400
    },
    "fees": {
        "charge1": 29,
        "charge2": 29,
        "chargetest": 29,
        "charge7": 29
    },
    "__v": 0,
}
```

I tried this, but no success :

```
module.exports.deleteOneBalance = (req, res) => {
    let data = req.body

    if (!ObjectID.isValid(req.params.id))
        return res.status(400).send('ID unknown : ' + req.params.id);

    BalanceModel.update(
        { _id: req.params.id },
        {
            $unset: { "incomes.salairetest": "400" }
        }), (err, docs) => {
            if (!err) res.send('Deleted. ' + data)
            else console.log('Error : ' + err)
        }
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: See how to refer to [embedded fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/).

Comment: Please use the correct terms. What do you mean by "file"? Why do you ask for "remove" but in your code you try an update. See [Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/)

Comment: I just want to remove one 'key/value' in the "incomes" category. And I use update because I saw example with update and $unset

Comment: Ok, but what do mean by *one 'key/value' in the "incomes"*? You need to know which one you like to remove - or which ones you like to keep.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Well, in my front there is a button on the side of each data. So if the customer click on the button next to "income1": "700", then it delete "income1": "700" from the object { incomes: {} } without removing other datas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove/unset specific value/(s) from the documents then you have to provide the complete path of that key.

Let's take an example if you want to remove `anyKeyNameIWant` then your path will be `incomes.anyKeyNameIWant` and the update query will be like this

```
db.sample.update(
    {
      _id: ObjectId("60c763df3d260204865d2069")},
    {
      $unset: {"incomes.anyKeyNameIWant":""}
    })
```

In your code, you are passing an object having the key `incomes` in `$unset` which will remove the complete `incomes` key from the document

Here is the link to the official document in case you want more details [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't understand because I tried your code, and it does not delete the field. I tried with updateOne, and same result :/

Comment: Can you tell in detail what exact query you tried? what was the result?

Comment: I updated my post with my controller. My route is a 'delete' route. Not a POST. Do you agree with this ?

Comment: With the updated code you got what result?

The route is okay. It won't have much impact on the query

Comment: it worked ! now I just have to find the dynamic way to do it :). thanks !!

Comment: Okay... Great! :)
Can you just update how it worked?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to delete fields with dynamic field names.

One solution is this one:

```
var unset = {};
unset["incomes." + "anyKeyNameIWant"] = null;
db.balanceModel.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, { $unset: unset })
```

Or you can use an aggregation pipelinie like this:

```
db.balanceModel.updateOne(
   { _id: req.params.id }, 
   [
      { $set: { incomes: { $objectToArray: "$incomes" } } },
      { $set: { incomes: { $filter: { input: "$incomes", cond: { $ne: ["$$this.k", "anyKeyNameIWant"] } } } } },
      { $set: { incomes: { $arrayToObject: "$incomes" } } }
   ]
)
```

Comment: I did something less beautiful  so I'm gonna steal your first solution. Thank you mate !